# Treeview node fonts not showing in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm trying to create a collapsible tree view box diagram like this

[image]

this is working properly in Chrome and Firefox. But in IE, these fonts inside nodes not showing.

[This URL include source code](https://github.com/swayvil/d3js-tree-boxes)

To make this solve I added following lines to **index.html**

```
<style>
html,body { height:100%; } 
#wrapper { height:100%; }
.section { height:100%; }
</style>
```

But this does not show any error or console log error.

[Live Demo can See Here](https://bl.ocks.org/swayvil/raw/b86f8d4941bdfcbfff8f69619cd2f460/)

Comment: IE11 and below [does not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) `foreignobject` tags.

Comment: Ohh thanks for showing

Comment: @Mark seems I don't have alternative for `foreignobject`

Comment: Alternative is to just use SVG's `<text>` tags.

Comment: not work that one also